# Rating the success of a classifier by comparing return boolean (1/0) to given value in 2D array

Tags: python, classification

I have an array "D" that contains dogs and their health conditions.
The classifier() method returns either 1 or 0 and takes one row of the 2D array as input.
I want to compare the classifier result to column 13 of the 2D array
In an ideal case the classifier would always return the same value as specified in that column.
Now I try to calculate the total hitrate of the classifier by adding up successes and dividing it by the total number of results.

So far I have worked out an enumerate for loop to hand over rows to the classifier in sequence.

```
def accuracy(D, classifier):

for i, item in enumerate(D):

        if classifier(item)==D[i,13]
        #Compare result of classifier with actual value

            x+=1 #Increase x on a hit

acc=(x/D.length)
#Divide x by length of D to calculate hitrate eg. "0.5"; 100% would be "1"

return acc
```

There is probably a simple formatting error somewhere or I have an error in my logic.
(Am 2 Days into Python now)
I think I might not be doing the if compare correctly.

Comment: I see at least three errors: 1) D is not defined, 2) classifier is not defined, 3) there's no colon at the end of your 'if' line

Comment: 4th Error: D.length can't be used on 2D array apparently. "len(D)" works

Comment: 5th Error: x needs to be defined before the loop so it stays alive to use outside of the loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming both `D` and `classifier` are defined, there are some errors in your code which should all give reasonable error messages (apart from the float casting, that one can be tricky with python).

You're both missing a `:` in the if-query, as well as you're trying to access the array `D` like `D[i, 13]` which isn't allowed. 2D-arrays is accessed with another set of `[]`, like `D[i][13]`. However, since you're already enumerating the 2D-array, you may as well use the `item[13]` to get the value.

Lastly, if you want a decimal value at the end you'll also need to cast at least one of the values to a float, like `float(x)/D.length`, otherwise it will just round it to 0 or 1.

**Fixed code:**

```
for i, item in enumerate(D):
    if classifier(item) == D[i][13]:
  # if classifier(item) == item[13]: # This should also work, you can use either.
        x += 1 #Increase x on a hit

acc = (float(x)/D.length)
# Divide x by length of D to calculate hitrate eg. "0.5"; 100% would be "1"
return acc
```

Comment: D and classifier are indeed defined. Thank you for the corrections. This is part of an online tutorial on Machine-learning I try to complete. Sadly they work with small tasks (can be beneficial) and the method gets executed on website, so I don't get compiler error output.